# Forward a port with NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to forward an python application to a directory. I know I worded this badly, let me try and explain it better

What I currently have:

NGINX on port 80
Static HTML files on /var/www/html

Python API on port 5500
localhost:5500/apiEndpoint (for example)

How can I change it so if I go to
localhost:80/api/apiEndpoint
it gives me localhost:5500/apiEndpoint
?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a mask of that location, you can try:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name domain.com;

    location ~ ^/api/apiEndpoint/(.*)$ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5500/apiEndpoint/$1;
    }
}
```

Hope i understood your question correctly.

Comment: Yes you did thanks. However, I have another endpoint that is like this: /api/parameter1/param2/param3. Would this work for that? Sorry for any weird notifications, mobile is buggy.

Comment: Im having some issues. After adding your example, nginx cant restart. Error: https://pastebin.com/BNbsgrry

Here is my implementation:
```location /api/getTrucks {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5500/getTrucks;
        }

        location ~ ^/api/addTruck/(.*)$ {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5500/addTruck/;
        }```

The first location block works, but the second does not.

Comment: on the second one, you're missing something in the `proxy_pass` directive. That's the `$1` at the end. Sorry, i updated my answer, i forgot to add it after testing it :(

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It looks like it works.